# merge two images with alpha channel

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have two images, one with and other without alpha channel. Thus, image `A` and `B` has a shape of *(x,y,4)* and *(x,y,3)* respectively.

I want to merge both images in a single tensor using `python`, where `B` is the background and `A` is the upper image. The final image must have a shape of (x, y, 3). I tried if scikit-image or cv2 is capable of doing this, but I couldn't found any solution.

Comment: here is a link for alpha blending using matlab https://github.com/techmn/ImageBlending

Comment: do you want to blend two images or merge them?

Comment: The goal is to do it with python.

Comment: I want to overlap one over the other, where the upper image is partially transparent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge one RGBA and one RGB images in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578600/how-to-merge-one-rgba-and-one-rgb-images-in-opencv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is alpha blending in python

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

alpha = 0.4

img1 = cv2.imread('Desert.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('Penguins.jpg')

#r,c,z = img1.shape

out_img = np.zeros(img1.shape,dtype=img1.dtype)
out_img[:,:,:] = (alpha * img1[:,:,:]) + ((1-alpha) * img2[:,:,:])
'''
# if want to loop over the whole image
for y in range(r):
    for x in range(c):
        out_img[y,x,0] = (alpha * img1[y,x,0]) + ((1-alpha) * img2[y,x,0])
        out_img[y,x,1] = (alpha * img1[y,x,1]) + ((1-alpha) * img2[y,x,1])
        out_img[y,x,2] = (alpha * img1[y,x,2]) + ((1-alpha) * img2[y,x,2])
'''

cv2.imshow('Output',out_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: How does a JPG have ARGB color? This does not answer the question, IMHO. Don't know how this can be the accepted answer. It does not use the alpha channel of the upper picture.

Comment: Kindly check what is alpha blending first https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html . The answer does not say that it uses alpha channel.

Comment: OP: "I have two images, one with and other without alpha channel" What is (x,y,4) if not RGBA?

Comment: If you are using png images and want to use alpha mask then you can see this tutorial https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Comment: Also, if you don't want transparency in your final image you can simply delete the 4th / alpha channel

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works, however I have a more efficient one:

```
alpha = A[:,:,3]
A1 = A[:,:,:3]

C = np.multiply(A1, alpha.reshape(x,y,1)) + np.multiply(B, 1-alpha.reshape(x,y,1))
```